# Listeners and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, listener

I feel that this might be a a silly question, but I'm not that experienced with listeners... Anyways, I have a question regarding threads and listeners; consider this code (might not be syntactically correct, doing this off the top of my head):

```
public class Stuff {
    private SimpleLongProperty time = new LongProperty(this, "time");
    private Executor execute;

    public Stuff(Clock clock) {
        time.bind(clock.getValue);
        execute = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    public void someAction() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            execute.execute(scheduleTask());
        }
    }

    public Runnable scheduleTask() {
        time.addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> {
            //Code here
        });
    }
}
```

When someAction() is called and calls scheduleTask() 5 times to add 5 listeners, will each listener execute code inside its own thread when time is updated? or will it execute the code in the main thread since that's where time resides?

Comment: The listeners will be called from the thread context they are called in (the executors threads in this case)

Comment: "the code might not be syntactically correct, doing this off the top of my head" - you'll probably get more answers next time when you'll provide syntactically correct minimal example that can be compiled.

Comment: @J-Alex JUnit cases for the win!

Comment: Post as an answer (not an edit to question) and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get on a workstation to write the code and test it, found my answer.

```
public class Stuff {
    private LongProperty time = new SimpleLongProperty(this, "time");
    private Executor execute;

    public Stuff(Clock clock) {
        time.bind(clock.getValue);
        execute = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });
    }

    public void someAction() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            execute.execute(scheduleTask(i));
        }
    }

    public Runnable scheduleTask(int i) {
        time.addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> {
            System.out.println("Task " + i + ": " + Thread.currentThread());
        });
    }
}
```

The above code will have print:

```
Task 0: Thread[JavaFX Application Thread, 5, main]
Task 1: Thread[JavaFX Application Thread, 5, main]
Task 2: Thread[JavaFX Application Thread, 5, main]
Task 3: Thread[JavaFX Application Thread, 5, main]
Task 4: Thread[JavaFX Application Thread, 5, main]
```

Changing someAction() and scheduleTask() function into something like this:

```
public void someAction() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scheduleTask(i);
    }
}

public void scheduleTask(int i) {
    Runnable test = () -> {
        System.out.println("Task " + i + ": " + Thread.currentThread());
    };
    time.addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> {
        execute.execute(test);
    });
}
```

Will yield the following:

```
Task 0: Thread[Thread-16, 5, main]
Task 1: Thread[Thread-17, 5, main]
Task 2: Thread[Thread-20, 5, main]
Task 3: Thread[Thread-19, 5, main]
Task 4: Thread[Thread-18, 5, main]
```